# How to set the url for XMLHttpRequest in JS?

Tags: url

In somefile.html, I use a JS which includes this for an XMLHttpRequest:

request.open('GET', 'static/name.json', true);
It works well when I call render_template('somefile.html') from the place

@app.route('/')
(Since the request opens the file here: http://localhost:5000/static/name.json

But when I need to call render_template('somefile.html') from other place like this:

@app.route('/conference//modifysession/', methods=['GET','POST'])
Here is the error showed in Chrome Developer:

http://localhost:5000/conference/16/modifysession/static/name.json 404 (NOT FOUND)
So the request automatically add the header to the URL of the file that I don't want it does.

How can I cut that automatically added part from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you are using in your get request is a relative url, if you use '/static/name.json' (note the leading /) in your get request, it would be for http://localhost:5000/static/name.json

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me a lot of time, and it's just a '/'! :-)